# Can you tell me why i get the Error Message invalid syntax on my command

Tags: python

```
from random import*
from tkinter import*

players=['wq','qwe','qwe']

players_to_random=[]

window = Tk()
window.title("Game is ON")

w= Label(window, bg="yellow")

def onclick():
     players_to_random.append(text)
     print(players_to_random)

def showButtons():
     for i in players:
          btn = Button(window, text=i command=onclick)
          btn.pack(side=LEFT)

showButtons()
```

I get the Error command invalid syntax but as far as i know it is possible to use command as a parameter for Buttons.So why does it show this Error

Comment: You forgot to indent the block in the last `for` loop. Also, for your future questions, please always include the complete error traceback, so that we don't have to try and guess where the error took place.

Comment: Also, it's `players_to_random.append` with a final **d**.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille sorry the error just said syntax error but yeah is hould have mentioned it was on my command. also my code is indented i just didnt copy it well since it is on my pi which is currently on another screen. so that cannot be the answer to it.and i checked my code append is with a d there not with a t.also edited it on the code

Comment: It never only says SyntaxError: the message always includes the line where the error was met. Please copy the **exact** error message.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille i just checked again it really does say only invalid syntax. it just displays the command as red  and thats it. nothing on the shell

Comment: We don't even know what this 'command' is supposed to be. Unless you reproduce, in your question, exactly what you typed and what you got, there is no way you can get help, as there is no way for us to know what happened. And I insist on **exactly**, letter for letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the indentation and syntaxis in the whole `shouButtons` function.

The block of code in the *for loop* must be indented. Also there is a comma missing between `Button` parameters `text` and `command`.

```py
def showButtons():
     for i in players:
         btn = Button(window, text=i, command=onclick)
         btn.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Comment: i have it like that its jsut nor working. i copied it wrong sorry. its on my pi and i couldnt copy it since its on another screen.ill edit my post

Comment: Take a look at my last edit! Missing comma `,`

Comment: my god am i stupid. thank you Josep that fixxed the problem

Comment: That's some stupid errors that can happen, if you can use some IDE as errors are much easier to find out!